# AngularJS: Connect two services with each other

Tags: angularjs

I have following to services:

dataService (should get data from the apiService, and then sort/group/filter the data).
apiService (should get the data from server. Also, when updated data comes in (websockets), the data should be pushed to dataService).

Now, it looks like, two services cant be connected to each other.
How can my dataService now get updates? I had following idea, but im not sure, if this is best practice:

- dataService calls apiService.init()
- in apiService.init(): Get Data from API/Server and safe it in var data
- dataService then gets the data from apiService.data via $watch, so every time the data gets updated, dataService will be notified.

What do you think? Is there some better way to do that? Thank you very much!

**Edit:**

This wont work:

```
var apiService = angular.module('apiService', []);

apiService.service('apiService', ['$http', 'dataService', function($http, dataService) {
    return {
        foo: "foo"
    };
}]);


var dataService = angular.module('dataService', []);

dataService.service('dataService', ['$http', 'apiService', function($http, apiService) {
    return {
        foo: "foo"
    };
}]);
```

**Edit 2:**

Will show me in Firebug:

Error: [$injector:cdep] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/cdep[...]

Comment: Seems fine...what's wrong / what's the question?

Comment: If there is an better way to do that, or even better, if there is an good way to make two services able to communicate with each other.

Comment: Your 2 services do communicate with eachother..

Comment: I can not use "dataService.randomFunction()" in apiService and "apiService.randomFunction()" in dataService at the same time. This is what i mean with "communicate with eachother". I can not use the functions of the other service in each service.

Comment: Can you post the code for both the services... this should just be as simple as injecting the services into one another

Comment: Sure, I edited my first post. Even this simple structure wont work.

Comment: It won't work as there is a cyclic dependency between the services, and dependency injector would fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your services don't work due to cyclic dependency between them.

Your proposed solution should work fine, but can be improved further by using promises, like the pseudo code below:

```js
var apiService = angular.module('apiService', []);

// Note that 'apiService' no longer has 'dataService' as a dependency
apiService.factory('apiService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      get: function() {
        // Return $http promise
        return $http.get(...);
      }
    };
  }
]);


var dataService = angular.module('dataService', []);

// Now, only 'dataService' depends on 'apiService'
dataService.factory('dataService', ['$http', 'apiService',
  function($http, apiService) {
    return {
      // This can further return a promise like below
      get: function() {
        return apiService.get()
          // Execute 'then' once the promise returned by the apiService.get() is resolved (i.e. date received)
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
      }
    };
  }
]);
```